# Changing a fixed footer to unfixed when you scroll to the bottom the page

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, footer

I have a fixed footer in two sections, the top is fixed and the bottom is hidden. When I scroll to the bottom of the page I would like the bottom section to display and the fixed footer to become unfixed and sit on top of the bottom part of the footer.

Here is the js fiddle so you can see why I am trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/8w8ttj6k/

Heres my html

```
<div class="container-fluid full-width">
    <footer class="footer primary-color">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="navbar-fixed-bottom text-center primary-color">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">Projects</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">Like us</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">Google Maps</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">Email Us</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="extension text-center js-footer">
                       <div class="col-sm-6">
                            &copy;HEM Building and Services
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#">Sitemap</a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
   </div>
```

css

```
 .js-footer{
display: none;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Jquery

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {   
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
     $("div").toggleClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");   
     $("div").removeClass("js-footer");
   }
 });
```

Can someone give me some help or point me in the right direction please, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the edge of the footer then compare it to the window `scrollTop()` if the scroll passes beyond the edge then remove the *fixed* class

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var footerEdge = $(window).height() - $('div.footer').height() - $('div.sub-footer').height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollTop > footerEdge){
        $("div.sub-footer").removeClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
    }
    else{
        $("div.sub-footer").addClass("navbar-fixed-bottom");
    }
});
```

Notice that I added 2 classes to your HTML, and removed the `js-footer` (not necessary)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8w8ttj6k/1/

Comment: thanks for your feedback, it does not seem to removing the navbar-fixed-bottom class though

Answer (score 0):

There is **ScrollToFixed** jQuery plugin, which can easily solve your prob. [ScrollToFixed](http:////https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed)

Here the fiddle link : - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/167/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="banner">
        <h1>Banner</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="content">
        <ul>
            <li id="left">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1><h2>Sit amet justo</h2><p>Leo sed sed pulvinar et magna id eget condimentum laborum vel suspendisse. Porttitor mattis aenean. Accumsan sed adipiscing. Amet penatibus rutrum vitae vehicula viverra amet nibh semper nunc libero tincidunt massa vitae sagittis urna consectetuer magna a diam parturient. Nec nec dolor. Venenatis purus quis. In turpis in. Officiis hic mauris lorem wisi maecenas.</p><h2>Velit sed eget donec placerat vestibulum</h2><p>Orci id gravida per neque nibh. Nullam sit commodo tincidunt et diam vitae pharetra sed. Tempus sit sodales. Voluptatem wisi mattis inceptos tellus dolor rhoncus sed et eu turpis torquent ligula eu dui lorem nec accumsan platea lacinia ac. Non faucibus per sit in vehicula magna lacus deleniti. Tincidunt per aliquam. Vestibulum adipiscing laoreet eget eros commodo. Laoreet molestie a eros in nec sed justo venenatis. Eu lorem gravida. Nisl non a sociis convallis leo. Est nunc nisl porta dignissim turpis. Sapien sed nulla. Amet mi diam. Sem risus accumsan. Posuere viverra convallis. Est at netus. Tortor eget quam. Wisi nulla erat vestibulum tempor eu hendrerit vel dolor. Aliquam magnis sed etiam felis eros.</p><h2>Scelerisque in justo neque ultricies vel eget libero quam vitae metus ante nonummy amet augue</h2><p>Velit tellus enim. Vitae et ultrices. Odio torquent ligula. Quam in a scelerisque malesuada non. Sem enim congue sed odio libero. Lacinia commodo feugiat sed nonummy lobortis erat maecenas vivamus. Lectus diam pede. Eget risus mauris. In dapibus libero suspendisse pellentesque urna. Id metus libero. Metus id accumsan curabitur id congue. Elementum diam placerat posuere vivamus felis. Arcu ante vestibulum. Orci ut ut magna nibh eu aliquam mi qui vel pretium nullam. Tellus ligula malesuada. Consequat id nulla. Feugiat suscipit ligula dolor amet congue urna etiam amet accumsan consequat distinctio natoque placerat nec. Eget lectus mauris molestie fusce dui. Vel consectetuer imperdiet tempus at sed. Proin aliquam nec. Ligula sit elit eget faucibus cras arcu in rhoncus. Lorem id integer. Vestibulum nec cum. Ligula aliquam tellus elit nisl lectus in diam tortor wisi mauris tempus.</p><p>Fermentum ipsum augue. Lectus in nunc vulputate tellus neque tortor erat cursus. Congue wisi enim. Nam eget dui auctor amet quis donec ipsum nibh. Nisl leo magna officia leo nibh.</p><h2>Mollis in ornare</h2><p>Nec a ut. Ut nullam urna. Quis tortor mauris blandit non corrupti. Rutrum in at id dignissim dictum. Duis ac ornare parturient ultrices amet odio feugiat aenean cras mus pede. Praesent egestas netus. Urna esse pharetra commodi commodo curabitur. A lacinia sed etiam ut vel maxime platea porta odio mollis non nisl nulla nullam. Vitae impedit pulvinar.</p><h2>Sem velit maiores</h2><p>Accumsan blandit ut. Varius velit ante. Leo tincidunt nulla lorem gravida nulla tempus volutpat donec phasellus aliquet nec. Sapien tempor id pharetra magna mi. Nunc fusce venenatis nam mi nam. Eget senectus convallis donec urna suscipit donec natoque lacinia rutrum lorem est adipiscing sed lectus. Dictumst faucibus ut. Vulputate sodales ipsum. Purus vehicula sed vestibulum eget integer.</p><h2>Ut turpis tempor integer fusce bibendum sem ipsum rutrum</h2><p>Nec in nibh. A amet condimentum. Commodo fringilla amet sit ut quis. Facilisi ac a ut id morbi. Aut pretium orci donec dui vel risus eros amet quis ut molestiae. Molestie nulla sem vestibulum urna aptent aliquam etiam auctor. Erat eu duis. Imperdiet vestibulum ut. Nibh risus fusce viverra wisi lectus.</p><h2>Sed curabitur ut vel condimentum fermentum a felis suspendisse</h2><p>Neque lacus lorem ut massa lacinia. Amet nulla est. Vitae in vel turpis diam elit lacinia amet quis. Sem a in. Architecto magna sit vel vehicula elit ullam consectetuer non. Vel vulputate elit facilisis accumsan justo. Ridiculus pharetra fusce. A volutpat curabitur. Senectus amet in elementum ipsum ut sit eros tellus.</p><h2>Phasellus enim metus vestibulum scelerisque mauris</h2><p>Donec nisl massa. Hendrerit suscipit turpis sed eget quis. Mauris wisi aenean amet semper morbi. Orci hendrerit vestibulum dolor a semper nullam nesciunt amet.</p><p>Erat ac non. Accumsan arcu mauris. Consectetuer vivamus convallis. Vestibulum neque vitae risus vivamus ut. Egestas elit eget. Venenatis mattis orci. Malesuada eget massa vitae est nec lacus et parturient nunc enim curabitur mollis vitae dictumst et malesuada non amet wisi amet sit lacus cras quis accumsan tortor tempore vulputate ante. Corrupti est sem dignissim ante vehicula ac cursus in tempus suspendisse at. Neque pariatur sed. Ac malesuada a. Hac duis pellentesque. Libero varius fugiat. Iaculis aliquam ac eros tempus sit sit in fusce. Luctus wisi amet. Vestibulum est vitae ut libero massa. Eu hendrerit velit. Et per massa congue vivamus sapien. Nibh nibh pulvinar. Libero velit est. Et lorem ipsum. Pretium sagittis nisl. Id ut viverra. Arcu dis sapien vehicula amet lacus sodales sagittis quam minim in mauris integer ante eu. Nisl id id eget sed molestie nec ac mauris nonummy proin porttitor. Vestibulum orci a sed in ligula.</p><h2>Lorem pede adipiscing massa eu eros</h2><p>Proin a at. Sagittis congue vitae. Eu arcu sem. A pede cras volutpat faucibus dui. Est ridiculus vestibulum blandit a dui montes dignissim mauris ac tellus diam. Rutrum gravida orci id eget morbi. Nec ut mollis. Dolore nulla donec. Nunc accumsan consectetuer. Erat orci vel. Primis erat nostra nec laoreet tempor eos porttitor sem hendrerit dignissim venenatis faucibus vel pellentesque. Lobortis in mi vitae donec metus faucibus amet viverra at ut dolor varius felis ante blandit sit litora ac autem ante. Pellentesque pede quisque. In nonummy pulvinar. Eget nunc quam. Massa torquent ut penatibus hendrerit et nulla scelerisque odio dolor vitae quis. In in quam dolor nec arcu. Magna vitae feugiat. Donec fermentum bibendum.</p><h2>Pretium dui dui</h2><p>Convallis wisi urna. Ipsum tellus ultricies. Non ac pretium. In non accumsan purus nec aliquip hendrerit fusce ornare ut turpis quis dictum tincidunt in vestibulum fringilla ad. In et dui. Eget tellus quisque arcu varius per tellus neque sit convallis nulla tellus. Nam faucibus aliquam. Vitae vel sed turpis nascetur ultricies aliquam vitae ultricies sed lobortis vestibulum sapien non eu. Sem amet nulla. Leo elit ipsum imperdiet sit dictumst. Enim turpis vivamus. Posuere odio ipsum in augue quisque nisl duis metus. Etiam imperdiet curabitur. Quis velit arcu. Ipsum turpis libero vel donec et. Ac risus a tempus.</p><h2>Sit amet dolore</h2><p>Praesent ipsum nibh ut curabitur justo. Ut proin faucibus. Ornare molestie magnis nec tempus ultricies eu amet sed. Et egestas aptent. Vel dignissim justo sodales suscipit lorem quis ullamcorper lacinia. Ac ligula nascetur. Tortor non leo at lacus non feugiat nisl aut suscipit nec ac rhoncus sed ipsum. Mauris condimentum erat rutrum ultricies justo.</p><h2>Rhoncus mauris vivamus</h2><p>Consectetuer quam euismod id accumsan a tellus ultrices quam suspendisse metus sit aliquam nec fermentum. Fusce aenean wisi. Purus eget rutrum non risus duis. Risus varius commodo egestas diam est. Dictum tellus nullam pede in ligula egestas neque pharetra vel justo non. Eu pharetra vestibulum. Mauris pede mauris. Erat a tellus. Orci vivamus mauris in morbi et.</p><h2>Scelerisque diamlorem sollicitudin</h2><p>Elementum libero etiam magna vitae velit scelerisque purus suspendisse. Amet torquent diam. In lacus vestibulum a ligula etiam. Vel convallis sapien. Cras platea rutrum. Leo pede volutpat. Ullamcorper dui sollicitudin consectetuer donec amet cras lorem nunc mattis sed dapibus metus enim ligula. Volutpat eu dictum mus vel ultrices. Sit nunc mattis. Mus donec tellus amet in a quaerat non vivamus sed in condimentum. Lacus posuere in. Condimentum sodales lacinia. Eget ante sagittis quisque duis scelerisque praesent tristique ut. Ipsum justo nulla viverra ornare in nam lectus aliquam.</p><p>Donec eget id est nulla nisl ipsa sollicitudin lectus vel fusce neque. Phasellus egestas commodo. Orci ipsum ut. Etiam vitae turpis vitae sed velit. Orci sollicitudin at. Felis id sem. Pharetra nisl dui nam enim non. Donec ullamcorper cras ligula dui mattis eget proin vitae. Nisl suspendisse tristique laoreet in etiam. Ac maecenas bibendum dis vel suspendisse. Et quisque integer. In lacus magna vel in aenean dolor facilisis nec. Mi ad tincidunt a nec felis duis nec nulla id sit vitae elementum egestas gravida. Wisi maecenas lectus. Nec ut nullam.</p><h2>Asperiores lectus minim</h2><p>Lorem integer faucibus lorem eget augue. Vulputate eget facilisis eu sollicitudin eget. Justo libero tincidunt tincidunt quam lacus. Leo ipsum felis. Eget potenti suscipit. Porta at omnis aliquam eleifend luctus. Est morbi tristique libero pellentesque nunc nec consectetuer in eget ante arcu eget sit integer. Metus magna sem vitae quam luctus id in sit neque suspendisse lacinia. Et arcu eget ac ante vivamus. Vitae magna cursus. Sollicitudin a vivamus. Pede eu nunc vehicula erat ipsum. Fusce quisque tincidunt. Fermentum sed aliquam elementum ut vitae wisi curabitur eget. Posuere nulla in curabitur sapien nascetur. Et proin maecenas integer hendrerit ultricies sed sed eu eget feugiat sem pellentesque velit eu. Suspendisse dui lectus. Ut tincidunt vitae. Et molestie donec.</p><h2>Auctor malesuada lorem</h2><p>In feugiat ut aliquam turpis vehicula. Dolor aut in gravida in nam eget euismod erat. Dignissim dictum non. Elit erat lorem ipsum lorem ac leo at turpis tristique amet aliquam morbi et per aliquam suspendisse cras. Sed elementum mi. Magna gravida facilisis ante dis mattis. Accumsan magnis elementum. Lacus dolor dictum. Sit vivamus integer. Nonummy ut torquent. Massa penatibus sit. Condimentum pulvinar ullamcorper. Vulputate laoreet primis lacus nec donec dictum eu pellentesque eros dictum amet risus dui.</p>
            </li>
            <li id="right">
                <ul id="summary">
                    <li class="title">Summary</li>
                    <li class="contents">
                        <p>Leo sed sed pulvinar et magna id eget condimentum laborum vel suspendisse.</p><p>Porttitor mattis aenean. Accumsan sed adipiscing. Amet penatibus rutrum vitae vehicula viverra amet nibh semper nunc libero tincidunt massa vitae sagittis urna consectetuer magna a diam parturient.</p><p>Nec nec dolor. Venenatis purus quis. In turpis in. Officiis hic mauris lorem wisi maecenas.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
    </li>
    <li class="footer-content">
        <h2>Sit amet justo</h2><p>Leo sed sed pulvinar et magna id eget condimentum laborum vel suspendisse. Porttitor mattis aenean. Accumsan sed adipiscing. Amet penatibus rutrum vitae vehicula viverra amet nibh semper nunc libero tincidunt massa vitae sagittis urna consectetuer magna a diam parturient. Nec nec dolor. Venenatis purus quis. In turpis in. Officiis hic mauris lorem wisi maecenas.</p><p>Lorem integer faucibus lorem eget augue. Vulputate eget facilisis eu sollicitudin eget. Justo libero tincidunt tincidunt quam lacus. Leo ipsum felis. Eget potenti suscipit. Porta at omnis aliquam eleifend luctus. Est morbi tristique libero pellentesque nunc nec consectetuer in eget ante arcu eget sit integer. Metus magna sem vitae quam luctus id in sit neque suspendisse lacinia. Et arcu eget ac ante vivamus. Vitae magna cursus. Sollicitudin a vivamus. Pede eu nunc vehicula erat ipsum. Fusce quisque tincidunt. Fermentum sed aliquam elementum ut vitae wisi curabitur eget. Posuere nulla in curabitur sapien nascetur. Et proin maecenas integer hendrerit ultricies sed sed eu eget feugiat sem pellentesque velit eu. Suspendisse dui lectus. Ut tincidunt vitae. Et molestie donec.</p><p>Proin a at. Sagittis congue vitae. Eu arcu sem. A pede cras volutpat faucibus dui. Est ridiculus vestibulum blandit a dui montes dignissim mauris ac tellus diam. Rutrum gravida orci id eget morbi. Nec ut mollis. Dolore nulla donec. Nunc accumsan consectetuer. Erat orci vel. Primis erat nostra nec laoreet tempor eos porttitor sem hendrerit dignissim venenatis faucibus vel pellentesque. Lobortis in mi vitae donec metus faucibus amet viverra at ut dolor varius felis ante blandit sit litora ac autem ante. Pellentesque pede quisque. In nonummy pulvinar. Eget nunc quam. Massa torquent ut penatibus hendrerit et nulla scelerisque odio dolor vitae quis. In in quam dolor nec arcu. Magna vitae feugiat. Donec fermentum bibendum.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    width: 960px;
}
body h1, h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
body p {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
body ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.banner {
    background-color: #aaa;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.content {
    padding: 5px;
}
.content li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer-content {
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}
#left {
    width: 770px;
}
#right {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#summary {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    width: 150px;
}
#summary .title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#summary .contents {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

**js**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header').scrollToFixed({
        preFixed: function() { $(this).find('h1').css('color', 'blue'); },
        postFixed: function() { $(this).find('h1').css('color', ''); }
    });
    $('#summary').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: $('.header').outerHeight() + 10,
        limit: $('.footer').offset().top - $('#summary').outerHeight() - 10,
        zIndex: 999,
        preFixed: function() { $(this).find('.title').css('color', 'blue'); },
        preAbsolute: function() { $(this).find('.title').css('color', 'red'); },
        postFixed: function() { $(this).find('.title').css('color', ''); },
        postAbsolute: function() { $(this).find('.title').css('color', ''); }
    });
    $('.footer').scrollToFixed( {
        bottom: 0,
        limit: $('.footer').offset().top,
        preFixed: function() { $(this).find('h1').css('color', 'blue'); },
        postFixed: function() { $(this).find('h1').css('color', ''); }
    });
});
```